# Oracle Pl/Sql Ora and Pls exception

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, oracle11g

What is the fundamental difference between Ora-XXXXX and PLS-XXXXX exceptions in oracle pl/sql.As per my understanding ORA is related to Database error and PLS is for programming error can some one put some light on this topic. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The meaning of the various error message prefixes doesn't seem to be clearly explained in the documentation. They are grouped in the error message manual but it doesn't really say what each group relates to - though you can usually work it out from the messages themselves.

But you're broadly right; at least that PLS errors are related to PL/SQL. ORA errors cover a wide spectrum and many of them can be because of 'programming' errors, depending on how you define that.

The [error messages introducton](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/intro.htm#i10726) says:

> All messages displayed are prefixed by text that indicates which
>   program issued the message. For example, the prefix "ORA" shows that
>   the message was generated by the Oracle products.

Since this is the Oracle documentation, saying the errors are generated by Oracle products doesn't add much, and the non-ORA codes come from Oracle products too.

The SQL*Plus user guide [includes a slightly more relevant summary](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#autoId19):

> If the error is a numbered error beginning with the letters "ORA",
>   look up the Oracle Database message in the Oracle Database Error
>   Messages guide or in the platform-specific Oracle documentation
>   provided for your operating system.
>
> If the error is a numbered error beginning with the letters "PLS",
>   look up the Oracle Database message in the Oracle Database PL/SQL
>   Language Reference.

... although the PLS errors are not in a separate document so that looks like a doc bug. The main [error documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/toc.htm) includes both core ORA errors and many other prefixes from specific products, including PLS errors, and also notes that 'messages are specific to one product and are documented in manuals for that product'.

If you go back to the [Oracle 9i error messages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/toc.htm) you can see a description of that the prefixes mean - PLS is 'PL/SQL and FIPS Messages' according to that. It isn't in later releases - maybe the lines between products were too blurred for it to be meaningful. I suspect it's largely down to which group has responsibility for assigning the messages to the codes for a product, and to some extent maybe has historic significance where products were acquired and adapted into the Oracle portfolio (as I believe PL/SQL itself was originally).

The `oerr` tool's usage statement calls the prefix a 'facility', which doesn't help much either.

If you see a PLS error then it doesn't even have to come from PL/SQL code you've written, or from a PL/SQL block. You can call a function from SQL that can get a PLS error, since they are (usually) implemented in PL/SQL. And you can get an ORA error while compiling PL/SQL.

So I'm not sure the distinction is entirely clear, but it's also not very useful. Whichever prefix your error has, you can look it up in the error messages book and see what it means and how to resolve it

Comment: I know you're saying that there's no clear differentiation in the main error docs it is differentiated by being split out. It's just a pity it doesn't tell you at the top what they generally refer to...

Comment: Thank @Ben, I've tried to clarify and expand that a bit. That is mostly what I meant.

Comment: It was a criticism of the documentation not your excellent answer @Alex! I saw this earlier and decided it just wasn't worth it; I'm very impressed that you've managed to squeeze so much information out of Oracle about the subject.